# How would I create a search box using IMPORTDATA?

Tags: search, gsheets

I'm trying to create a search box that displays the result in a different Spreadsheet. The one I am importing has only the names. It is in the A column with no heading.

I have this formula

=QUERY(IMPORTDATA("URL", "Sheet1!A1:A29"), "SELECT * WHERE A LIKE '%"&A1&"%'")

However, it returns this error "IMPORTDATA delimiter value is Sheet1!A1:A29. It should be a single character that is not a double quote or a blank space."

This formula below works fine if the data is in the same spreadsheet
=QUERY(D2:D30, "SELECT * WHERE D LIKE '%"&A1&"%'")

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own question. The solution is to use "Col1" instead of "A" to identify which column we are using.

Here's my final query
Kkk
=IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!A1:A29"),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 LIKE '%"&A1&"%'"),"NO RESULTS FOUND")